# Custom Validator and @interface List

Tags: java, validation

I'm trying to do my first custom validator. I defined my annotation :

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PojoValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface Pojo {

  String message() default "invalid pojo";

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
```

And in many tutorial on the web i see something like that at the end of the declaration :

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,
        ElementType.FIELD,
        ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,
        ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,
        ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {
        Email[] value();
    }
```

What is the purpose of this `@interface List`, how should it be written in my example and is it mandatory?

Comment: yes, it's all in Java

Comment: Alright. I just added the java tag. As a heads up, it's almost always a good idea to have the language you're writing in as a tag. For those of us answering, we tend to filter by the language tag, so something that's in java that isn't tagged as such tends to get missed. It also adds some needed context.

Comment: I'm new on this site, thanks for the tip. I'll do it now.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 1.7- you can't have multiple annotations of the same type. The way round this is with List. Say you have a class-level validation to check that 2 fields are equal and you want to use it twice (eg to validate that passwd = repeatPasswd and email = repeatEmail:

```
@ValidateEquals.List({
    @ValidateEquals(field1 = "pwd", field2="repPwd"),
    @ValidateEquals(field1 = "email", field2="repEmail")
})
public class MyForm
```

Not sure if it is mandatory, but it is highly recommended for class-level validators.